# will jre-1.8.0_252 app(.jar) work in jre-1.8.0_242?

Tags: java

I created a java application as .jar and I must run it on another computer. I programmed my application in jre-1.8.0_252 but in another computer jre-1.8.0_242 installed. I only have one try. will it work?

Comment: And what the application looks like? I this a kind of test where you should respond by yes or no or is this based on real-world needs? The short answer would be yes, it should work fine but why would you downgrade your version is you can install another compatible JRE version (and even post 8 version)?

Comment: First of all, you can't develop with a JRE, you probably mean JDK. JRE stands for Java Runtime Environment, so it is used only to run Java.  What version of JDK you used?